# docker-compose the latest stable version on ubuntu

Tags: docker-compose

When I update docker-engine to the latest version on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, I can see docker-engine is at the latest stable version based on https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

How come I don't see the latest stable version of docker-compose?

It is supposed to be **1.8.1** based on https://github.com/docker/compose/tags,
but it is **1.6.2** as you can see below

I couldn't find the information about *apt-get install* on official doc page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

```
> apt-cache policy docker-engine
docker-engine:
  Installed: 1.12.3-0~xenial
  Candidate: 1.12.3-0~xenial

> docker --version
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec

> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027

>lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu 20.04 with the latest version of docker-compose.

run:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.0.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

run:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

check that we have the latest version, run:

```
docker-compose --version
```

[github docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can install with

```
sudo curl -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.8.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"
```

and set permissions

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Ideally, it would be updated along with docker engine, but I didn't find the solution